# How to distribute buttons on left and right side of a window?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a window where I want to add buttons for Save and Cancel into items.

I know there is a buttons config but that one doesn't work with a zoom. So if I zoom in, I don't see any scrollbars.

That's why I think it might work if it is added to items (like other components).

I have this code:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            title: 'My Form',
            id: 'myform',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            width: 500,
            layout: {
                type: 'vbox',
            },

            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'textarea',
                    id: 'myText',
                    width: '100%',
                    anchor: '100% 95%',
                    hideLabel: true,
                    value: 'Some text'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    layout: {
                        type: 'hbox',
                        pack: 'right'
                    },
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            text: 'Highlight',
                            cls: 'green-button',
                            handler: function () {
                                Ext.getCmp('myText').setValue(Ext.getCmp('myText').getValue() + ' \nClicked!');
                            }
                        },
                         {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            text: 'Highlight2',
                            cls: 'green-button',
                            handler: function () {
                                Ext.getCmp('myText').setValue(Ext.getCmp('myText').getValue() + ' \nClicked!');
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
               
            ]
        });
    }
});
```

But no matter what I do the buttons always are shown as side by side... I would like to show buttons in bottom left and bottom right corner of a window.

[image]

How to fix this?

This is the link of the fiddle:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3pj6

Answer (score 0):

First you have to ensure that the parent container will take up all the space. Second, you add a component that will occupy all the available space "flex: 1". This will make the buttons one on each side. You can try this.

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            title: 'My Form',
            id: 'myform',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            width: 500,
            layout: {
                type: 'vbox',
            },

            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'textarea',
                    id: 'myText',
                    width: '100%',
                    anchor: '100% 95%',
                    hideLabel: true,
                    value: 'Some text'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    width: '100%',
                    layout: {
                        type: 'hbox',
                    },
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            text: 'Highlight',
                            cls: 'green-button',
                            handler: function () {
                                Ext.getCmp('myText').setValue(Ext.getCmp('myText').getValue() + ' \nClicked!');
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            flex: 1,
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            text: 'Highlight2',
                            cls: 'green-button',
                            handler: function () {
                                Ext.getCmp('myText').setValue(Ext.getCmp('myText').getValue() + ' \nClicked!');
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
               
            ]
        });
    }
});
```